# Modularity in OOP vs Procedural?

Tags: oop, object, module, modularity, procedural-programming

As part of a course, I've been asked to give a definition of Modularity in two cases. The Object-oriented programming and the Procedural one. After reading up on this concept I still do not understand how Modularity differs in those two. Could someone please highlight the major differences?

I've added the screenshot of the specific task to give you an idea of what I'm presented with.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the big difference between modular and object oriented programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034683/what-is-the-big-difference-between-modular-and-object-oriented-programming)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm either not educated enough on the topic to understand that it does answer it, or it refers to a slightly different situation. I have added a screenshot to give you an idea of the task I was given. All it says is Modularity (OOP) vs Modularity (Procedural). I'm not entirely sure where they want me to go with it. I should clarify that I'm a complete novice when it comes to Computer Science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has an article about "Procedural programming" where the two (procedural and object-oriented) are compared quite well. See the "Comparison with other programming paradigms" section of the article.

Link of the article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming

You can also read up on modularity there to understand the concept better.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that in Procedural programming a module would typically be a procedure/routine which operates on a data structure, whereas in OOP a module could be a class, an object, or a function?

Comment: Yes. Although I wouldn’t really say a function is a module in OOP terms. Also it’s worth noting that in PP each function has its own scope which helps make it modular. OOP essentially has everything that PP has and more since it has the capability of classes and objects where procedures and data structures can be bundled together. A module in OOP is most often said to be in the form of an object, which is an instance of a class. Class defines the type of object regarding behavior and attributes but not the current state and current data, that is only defined at run-time for each object.